# GreasePencil color doesn't change

Tags: rendering, materials, grease-pencil

I tried animating the color of a GresePencil stroke, changing it from black to white. I gave it a tint modifier and animated its material color, but it didn't work. The color does change when I copy the GreasePencil stroke and paste it into a new file, but not in this scene.

This problem doesn't occur in solid view, only in material and render preview.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scene was too dark. So I just had to turn off "use lights" in object data properties tab under layers.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome! Could you please go into a little more detail about the solution, and write where exactly the option can be found? Maybe a screenshot would also help. This would allow less experienced users to benefit from your answer. Thank you!